# Function IIF, how to make it take 2N + 1 arguments of logical expressions?, C #

Tags: c#, iif, iif-function

In Visual Basic, there is this **[IIF Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function)**, as in Crystal Report, etc ...

In C # itself, this function does not exist, but it is the same as doing something like this:

```
bool a = true;
string b = a ? "is_True" : "is_False";
```

But for the code to be a bit easier to read I wanted to do it as a function for C #, leaving it like this:

```
public static T IIf<T>(bool expression, T truePart, T falsePart)
{
     return expression ? truePart : falsePart;
}
```

Or to not operate with the real values ​​can also be done using delegates, to access the necessary values:

```
public static T IIf<T>(bool expression, Func<T> truePart, Func<T> falsePart)
{
    return expression ? truePart() : falsePart();
}
```

So far this works well ...

---

But **how can I modify this function so I can take 2N + 1 arguments?**

> (N - the number of logical expressions specified)

Example the desired result:

> Each odd argument specifies a logical expression;
>
> Each even argument specifies the value that is returned if the previous expression evaluates to true;
>
> The last argument specifies the value that is returned if the previously evaluated logical expressions yielded false.

```
int value = IIf(Name = "Joel", 1, Name = "Peter", 2, Name = "Maria", 3, 4);
```

Can someone give me a hand with this?

Environment: C # - Visual Studio 2017

Comment: This whole thing strikes me as a bad idea.  In my opinion the built-in ternary operator ?: is *much* easier to read that what you propose.

Comment: Other than using `params object[] args` and then working out all the details inside, you can't. The compiler doesn't support "variable number of **pairs** of arguments". Why can't you simply use the ternary operator directly?

Comment: Wrong assumption. IIF is not like a ternary operator. Both true part and false part are evaluated.

Comment: `int value = IIf(Name == "Joel", 1, IIf(Name == "Peter", 2, IIf(Name == "Maria", 3, 4)));`

Comment: A function like this is going to be unusable with more than just a handful of operations.  Personally I'd argue it's a bad idea to use it with any more than one condition, but even if you want to use it for a handful, you're not going to find an easier option than just writing out those handful of overloads by hand.  If you need more conditions than you can easily write overloads for by hand, then the caller of the method won't be able to understand what they're doing anyway.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen This may work, but would it work exactly as the result I want? Can you show me an example with the code?

Comment: Do you need this "IIf always evaluates both truepart and falsepart, even though it returns only one of them." part? (The code in the post is *very* different from what IIF docs you linked to say) Otherwise looks like just dictionary lookup or `switch`.

Comment: @rory.ap For me it was not a bad idea but this perhaps for lack of knowledge, If you consider it a bad idea I think I should learn from this to improve my code

Comment: How about `var nameLookupTable = new Dictionnary<string,int>{{"Joel", 1}, ... };` `int value = nameLookupTable[Name];`

Comment: @Steve Each odd argument specifies a logical expression;

Each even argument specifies the value that is returned if the previous expression evaluates to true;

...

The last argument specifies the value that is returned if the previously evaluated logical expressions yielded false.

Comment: @JustinLessard This would only work for `string` and` int` this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: @JustinLessard - dictionary lookup does not match IIF docs - it does not evaluate all options, just returns one...

Comment: Then use a switch case.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez ???? As long as you can compare keys any type would do... What do you mean "only works for string and int"? (it does not satisfy requirement in the question at all, but not because of type restriction)

Comment: @JustinLessard You are correct that a dictionary lookup is not the same as a series of evaluated conditional statements.  However *the particular problem you're describing is in fact best solved by dictionary lookup*, and trying to use consecutive conditional statements *is a bad way to solve that problem*.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I mean I'm using `T` to evaluate any type of data, and not a specific one

Comment: @J.Rodríguez And you can make a dictionary where the value is *any* type of data.  Dictionaries aren't limited to just storing `int`s.

Comment: @Servy I do not want to use Dictionary, I want to use that iif function specifically, but thanks, I'll look for another alternative or I'll use it recursively

Comment: What have your co-workers done to make you hate them so much?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez This is not IIf but Switch.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/switch-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, as noted in the comments, this is a bad idea. Newer versions of C# already support pattern-matching switches as a built-in feature of the language; use it.

Second, this is a bad idea because the API of "argument, case1, result1, case2, result2, ..." has a signature that is hard to express in the C# type system.

Were I forced to implement such an API, I would suggest using tuples:

```
public static R Switch<A, R>(
  A item, 
  R theDefault, 
  params (A, R)[] cases )
{
    foreach(var c in cases) 
        if (item.Equals(c.Item1))
            return c.Item2;
    return theDefault;
}
```

Or, make a helpful utility method and use it:

```
public static T FirstOrDefault(
  this IEnumerable<T> items,
  T theDefault,
  Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach(var i in items.Where(predicate))
      return i;
    return theDefault;
} 

public static R Switch<A, R>(
    A item, 
    R theDefault, 
    params (A, R)[] cases ) =>
  cases.FirstOrDefault(
    (item, theDefault),
    c => item.Equals(c.Item1)).Item2;
```

If you cannot use tuples because you're using an older version of C#, you could make your own pair type or use the key-value pair type.

But just do not go there. If you need a switch, write a switch. If you need a dictionary, write a dictionary.

Comment: It shows me this error: _The predefined type System.ValueTuple is neither defined nor imported_.

Based on my example, can you show me how to use it? Thanks

Comment: @J.Rodríguez: Did you make any attempt to answer that question for yourself? I suggest you do so.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using .NetFrameWork 4.5.2 and I must install the package

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the order of your parameters, which presumably you do if you're trying so hard to make the function replicate what you've seen elsewhere, then you can write something like this:

```
public T IIf<T>(params object[] objects) {

    for(var i = 0; i < objects.Length - 1; i += 2) 
        if((bool)objects[i])
            return (T)objects[i+1];

    return (T)objects[objects.Length - 1];

}
```

But it's a good lesson in why you would avoid something like this.  Firstly, you have to explicitly declare the type you're working with.  So you'd have to use it like this:

```
var value = IIf<int>(Name == "Joel", 1, Name == "Peter", 2, Name == "Maria", 3, 4);
```

Notice the passing of 'int' as a type parameter.  You can avoid that by changing the order of the parameters so that the default comes first.

But, if you're just willing to adopt a personal pattern, the nested ternary syntax can be quite readable:

```
var value = 
      Name == "Joel" ? 1
    : Name == "Peter" ? 2
    : Name == "Maria" ? 3
    : 4;
```

If you don't feel it's readable, then it's just because it takes some getting used to.  Imagine going the other way, from a C# developer to VB, and seeing 'IIF'.  You'd be thinking, "why do they add the extra 'I' in 'IF'?".  I should make a function "IF" that emulates "IIF".  But that would be a bad idea, wouldn't it?